# SQL Server Trimming and Count

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple select below:

```
Select * from transaction
where customer = 'AA'
```

The result I get is a few columns with company name, email address, value of transaction, date and also transaction ID. Now this is the important bit, I want to write a query where I can get a list of transaction id's as a count. HOWEVER, the id's are all different from each other in terms of their final few numbers:

ie

I have the following id:

`LV_AAAA_205_123456` or 
`LV_AAAA_205_123456_E_`  (as you can see this is the same but has *E*)

This is the main id. However if this transaction has been changed then it changes to the id below

```
LV_AAAA_205_123456_E_(2)
```

and if it changes again then it looks like this

`LV_AAAA_205_123456_E_(3)` and this can go on depending on how many times it changes.

What I want is a query that allows me to find how many times these original id's have been changed by looking at instances where they have (2), (3) on the end due their id's.

I want an end query which gives me an output of ONLY id's that have been changed and a column count of how many times the have been changed so the id `LV_AAAA_205_123456_E_(4)` will have a count of 4 next to it.

Sorry if i am unclear, please ask for my clarity. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Good example of how bad design fires back. I am wondering why is transaction ID maintained like this.

Comment: Good question but not sure this is how it is and i need help with my query

Comment: Thanks at EzLo for the edits much needed

Comment: Is the suffix `_E_` fixed? Will it always be there whenever a original transaction is retried?

Comment: Very good question and the answer is yes. So even if the id originally does not have _E_ like LV_AAAA_205_123456, when it is retried it will always be LV_AAAA_205_123456_E_(2)

Comment: Once you have worked out a function that does what you need, consider re-engineering the design. As an intermediate stage to mitigate the problem, you could use a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) to break the original string down into its logical components, and even index the computed columns for speed when doing your grouping/counting.

Comment: @Matt why not simply update the `RetryCount` (new column) of that transaction row!

Comment: @NikhilVartak That was what I meant by "re-engineering the design". We don't know what would need doing exactly, though, without knowing more details of the original design and the current constraints of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, as all changed records contain the number inside of brackets `()` at the end of the `transactionId`:

```
SELECT *,
       TRY_PARSE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(transactionId,
                                   CHARINDEX('(', transactionId)+1, 
                                   100),
                         ')',
                         '')
                 AS int) AS changeCount
FROM [transaction]
WHERE transactionID LIKE '%(%)'
```

Comment: Thanks matt, but it says there is an incorrect syntax near the second select

Comment: @Taz Sorry, that was a copy&paste mistake. :)

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks so much Matt :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this script

```
select 
    case 
      when transactionId like '%_E_%' 
      then isnull(TRY_PARSE(REPLACE(substring(transactionId, CHARINDEX('_E_(', transactionId, 0) + 4, LEN(transactionId)) , ')', '') as int), 1)
      else 0 
    end as ChangedTimes
from transaction
where customer = 'AA'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, it gives me an output but next to those that should have had a number > 1 it shows 1. So LV_AAAA_205_123456_E_(4) gives a count of 1 when it should be 4.

Comment: pls check it twice - output is correct `select 
     case 
      when 'LV_AAAA_205_123456_E_(4)' like '%_E_%' 
      then isnull(TRY_PARSE(REPLACE(substring('LV_AAAA_205_123456_E_(4)', CHARINDEX('_E_(', 'LV_AAAA_205_123456_E_(4)', 0) + 4, LEN('LV_AAAA_205_123456_E_(4)')), ')', '') as int), 1)
      else 0 
    end as ChangedTimes`